# Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours Sixth Edition by Rogers Cadenhead MP3 Chapter 20 MP3 File Error

Tags: java, file-io, arguments, runtime-error, filenotfoundexception

I am a java novice trying to go through the book listed in the title of this post. This is also my first question to post on stack overflow. There does not appear to be a forum for the book so I decided to ask here.

I am on Chapter 20: Reading and Writing Files in Java 24 Hours and have gotten to the ID3Reader.java project. I am using Netbeans 7 to create this project. The code is supposed to analyze an MP3 file (which I have made my argument using the absolute path) and skip everything but the last 128 bytes. Then, the remaining bytes are examined to see if they contain any ID3 data. If they do, the first three bytes are the numbers 84, 65, 71.
Then it displays the title, the artist, the album and the year in a descending order.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ID3Reader {
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    try {
        File song = new File(arguments[0]);
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(song);
        int size = (int) song.length();
        file.skip(size - 128);
        byte[] last128 = new byte[128];
        file.read(last128);
        String id3 = new String(last128);
        String tag = id3.substring(0, 3);
        if (tag.equals("TAG")) {
            System.out.println("Title: " + id3.substring(3, 32));
            System.out.println("Artist: " + id3.substring(33, 62));
            System.out.println("Album: " + id3.substring(63, 91));
            System.out.println("Year: " + id3.substring(93, 97));
        } else {
            System.out.println(arguments[0] + " does not contain"
                + " ID3 info.");
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error — " + e.toString());
    }
    }
```

Again I have set the argument to exactly where the MP3 file is and have even got the code from the website for this book.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\Where The Moon Came From - Moonbrows (Twin Of Pangaea).
```

But instead I get this error.

```
Error — java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have pulled my hair out trying to find something that would help me on this problem but I just cannot seem to find anything that I can translate to this problem. I would very much appreciate any information that you can give me. If there is any more information that is needed to be known before you can answer just say the word an I will get it.

Comment: Put the first argument of your program in commas: `java ID3Reader.class "c:\...\file.mp3"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\Where The Moon Came From - Moonbrows (Twin Of Pangaea)
```

Do you have that file? Maybe you forgot the `.mp3` at the end, or maybe you never had the file in the first place. If not, change the path to where your file is like this:

```
C:\Users\Somebody\Desktop\song.mp3
```

Also, if you want spaces in a path you must use quotes:

```
"C:\Path with spaces\More spaces\song_thing.mp3"
```

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH! It was so simple! most gracious!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to put the path between quotes when "setting the argument"; like so:

```
java ID3Reader "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\Where The Moon Came From - Moonbrows (Twin Of Pangaea)."
```

Comment: +1 - The problem is that the command shell is naively splitting the command into arguments at each sequence of spaces.  Adding the quotes tells the command shell "this should be passed as one argument".

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your file argument in quotes in your run command, otherwise the first string token will be used as `arguments[0]`, as passed in by the command shell:

```
java ID3Reader  "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\Where The Moon Came From - Moonbrows (Twin Of Pangaea).mp3"
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error message, the filename was parsed as `C:\Documents`.  This is because the space after `Documents` indicates the end of the first argument, and start of the second.  You need to wrap the argument in quotes for it to be treated as a single argument.

```
java ID3Reader "C:\Documents and Settings\..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem/error message but after copying that mp3 file to Eclipse Projects folder it worked well. The code is alright proble I think is creating a path to the file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).